Are AWS Lambda functions automatically queued in a way that's aware of concurrency limit?
Suppose I have AWS Lambda functions X and Y, and X immediately issues 5000 asynchronous calls to Y before exiting. The default concurrency limit is 1000, so only 1000 instances of Y will immediately start executing. The other 4000 will be throttled.
Assuming Y takes a significant amount of time to run, though not enough to timeout. Maybe a couple of minutes.
Is the system smart enough to keep the other 4000 calls in a queue until they can be run, so they all successfully run eventually?
Or will it go like 'try call 1001, fail because of throttling. Immediately retry, fail for the same reason. Hit the retry count limit, give up, dump that call in the DLQ. Same for the other 3999 calls.'
And does it matter whether X called Y directly, or by putting an item in a DynamoDB table, thereby triggering a stream event for which Y was registered?

Async invocations are queued per Invoking a Lambda function asynchronously and errors and throttling are described here.

You might enjoy reading this series of articles about how AWS Lambda operates: Operating Lambda: Performance optimization – Part 1 | AWS Compute Blog

@jarmod Yep. I have read the documentation, and if I'm understanding correctly, it seems to be saying 'kinda sorta, not as such, the first calls will bounce off the throttling and fail/retry, but exponential backoff will ultimately produce the desired result as long as the total doesn't go beyond six hours'. But hoping someone will clarify if I'm misunderstanding.
